# android findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId return null although the node id exists

Tags: android, accessibility

I am using Android's accessibility service recently, but I found that some nodes cannot be obtained with the findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId method, and the returned value is null. I want to know why?

Use uiautomatorviewer to view node information as shown below:

[image]

The code and execution are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried set idSelector to __text1__ ?

Comment: @cowboi-peng yes, i get same error

Comment: One does not need to try `text1` because it is clearly documented as: ...the fully qualified resource id is "foo.bar:id/baz"... Better try traverse through the whole view tree. Also check if `root` is really the root view of the activity.